# Django odd behaviour

Tags: python, django

Whenever I start a project in Django, independently of the name of the app or project, and irrespective of any urls or settings configuration, upon running `python manage.py runserver` and navigating to 127.0.0.1 I get the following error: `Not Found: /ball/ [10/Jan/2022 11:32:32] "GET /ball/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2337` and this displays in th browser:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ball/
Using the URLconf defined in ornaments.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, ball/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Why is Django looking for a route called `ball`?

Comment: Can you test with other browsers or just with `curl 127.0.0.1` maybe cache problem?

Comment: Same issue with any browser and even curl

Comment: if you type "127.0.0.1" in your browser and you get to "127.0.0.1:8000/ball/" (which is the message in django app) than it means you might have another server running on Port 80 that redirects to 127.0.0.1:8000/ball/. -     "TCPView" is a nice and simple tool if you are on Windows to see which process is listening on which Port

Comment: Where is your `template/view` for the root url?

Comment: @Sayse there is none. Even trying with just runserver immediately after startapp gives the same behaviour

Comment: You say you're "navigating to 127.0.0.1" so wheres the template/view you're attempting to navigate to?

Comment: I am navigating to 127.0.0.1:8000 to be precise. Whatever template I put or however I change the urls.py both in the project urls and in the app urls, whichever project or app I use or start the behavior is the same. It looks for `ball`. To be clear: if I start an empty project now called Sayse it will still look for /ball.

Comment: Do you have anything else running on port 8000 already? in other words, if you `runserver 0.0.0.0:8001` and navigate to `127.0.0.1:8001` do you still get the same issue

Comment: So actually it _was_ a cache problem. Clearing the cache from all three browsers fixed it. I don't understand how it could happen and also extend the behaviour to `curl`but whatever, I guess. Thanks @Sayse anyway.